# How can I push values in multidimensional array

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

Hy guys,

I need help for my trouble.
I want to push values into specific array key, I did something but I have a lot of null pushed.

I need something like this :

```
{
    "20": {
        "0":10,
        "1":20,
        "2":30
    },
    "30":{
        "0":10,
        "1":20,
        "2":30
    }
}
```

[Source here](https://jsfiddle.net/eL5tr12n/4/)

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  pushOrRemove($(this).data('value'), $(this).data('key'))
});

function pushOrRemove(value, array_key) {
  var attribute_values = [];
  if ($('[data-stored-values]').val().length == 0) {
    attribute_values[array_key] = [];
  } else {
    attribute_values[array_key] = JSON.parse($('#removed_variant_options').val());
  }

  attribute_values[array_key].push(value);

  $('[data-stored-values]').val(JSON.stringify(attribute_values))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value="10" data-key="20">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="20" data-key="20">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="30" data-key="20">Click</a>

<a href="#" data-value="10" data-key="30">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="20" data-key="30">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="30" data-key="30">Click</a>




<input type="text" data-stored-values>
```

Comment: None of this is an array.  They are all objects. `[]` denotes an array, `{}` is an object.

Comment: What is `removed_variant_options`?!!

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i forgot to change is actually $('[data-stored-values]') hidden input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  pushOrRemove($(this).data('value'), $(this).data('key'))
});

function pushOrRemove(value, array_key) {
  // get the variable you store the json in
  var $storedValues = $('[data-stored-values]');
  // if the json is not set, default to an empty object
  var attribute_values = JSON.parse($storedValues.val() || '{}');
  
  // if the key is not in the object yet, defaultto an empty array
  attribute_values[array_key] = attribute_values[array_key] || [];
  
  // get the index of the value
  var indexOfValue = attribute_values[array_key].indexOf(value);
  
  // if the index is -1, it's not in there, so add
  if (indexOfValue < 0) {
    attribute_values[array_key].push(value);
  } else {
    // the index was 0 or more, so remove it
    attribute_values[array_key].splice(indexOfValue, 1);
  }

  // update the stored json for the next interaction
  $storedValues.val(JSON.stringify(attribute_values));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-value="10" data-key="20">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="20" data-key="20">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="30" data-key="20">Click</a>

<a href="#" data-value="10" data-key="30">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="20" data-key="30">Click</a>
<a href="#" data-value="30" data-key="30">Click</a>




<input type="text" data-stored-values>
```